# Flutter Disabling Button Does Not Execute Function During Testing

Tags: flutter, dart

I am running into a weird scenario in Flutter with buttons and testing and I am hoping for some explanation, as I couldn't find any documentation or similar problems describing this.

I have a Button that looks something like this,

```
FilledButton(
    onPressed: state.valid && !state.loading ? () async {
        // debugger();
        await context.read<SignInCubit>().signIn();
    }: null,
    child: const Text('Sign In'))
```

This works fine when I run it in a simulator - the button is initially disabled when the form is empty. When I fill in the form, it becomes enabled again. When I click on the button to sign in, the button becomes disabled again.

The issue comes when I try to describe this in test,

```
testGoldens('should disable button when signing in',
        (WidgetTester tester) async {
      // prepare
      ...
      await tester.enterText(
          find.widgetWithText(TextFormField, 'E-mail'), 'valid@gmail.com');
      await tester.enterText(
          find.widgetWithText(TextFormField, 'Password'), 'validpassword');
      when(mockAuthService.signIn(
              email: anyNamed('email'), password: anyNamed('password')))
          .thenAnswer((realInvocation) async {
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
        return Future.value(User.empty());
      });

      // act
      await tester.tap(find.widgetWithText(FilledButton, "Sign In"));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 2));

      // verify
      await screenMatchesGolden(tester, tester.testDescription);
      verify(mockAuthService.signIn(
              email: anyNamed('email'), password: anyNamed('password')))
          .called(1);
      expect(
          tester
              .widget<FilledButton>(
                  find.widgetWithText(FilledButton, "Sign In"))
              .enabled,
          isFalse);
```

I am expecting thsi to call the mocked service, but it never does. The execution never seems to reach the debugger I placed in the async function either.

However, if I change the code to something like,

```
FilledButton(
    onPressed: () async {
        // debugger
        await context.read<SignInCubit>().signIn();
    },
    child: const Text('Sign In'))
```

The mocked service gets invoked successfully (because Mockito does not throw exception anymore), and if I put a debugger in the function, it also stops in there.

I am relatively new to Dart and Flutter, so this might be a noob question - why does the latter execute the async function assigned to `onPressed`, but the former with the ternary expression doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `await tester.pumpAndSettle()` also before the tap? Your FilledButton needs a refresh to install the click handler.